# Exception in loaddiing commerce catalog items in storefront

Tags: sitecore-commerce, sxa-storefront

I have installed sitecore commerce and now in storefront, When i am trying to navigate to the product list page, i get the following exception

> Message: An error occured while trying to contact the Commerce Service. Error code BadGateway
> An error occured while trying to contact the Commerce Service. Error code BadRequest
> Source: Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect+

Any ideas?

Comment: What version of XC, you are using? And check defaultEnvironment Sitecore.Commerce.Engine.Connect.config

Comment: It maybe due to the incorrect DB connection string setting. Can you please put up a copy of the log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In all the sitecore 9 and above versions, this error happens when the sitecore instance is not able to find out the correct instance of commerce engine.

The storefront will get the configuration from ShopsService URL and communicate with the corresponding commerce engines.

Here are 2 steps you must check when this happens

1. Go to showconfig.aspx and find the ShopsService and commerceOpsServiceUrl should point to https://localhost:5000. There might have been some override config files which is overwriting these values which you can find in showconfig url.
2. Check to see if commerce engine metadata specified in shopsServiceUrl is accessable. For example shopsServiceUrl https://localhost:5000/CommerceOps/$metadata#Commands/$entity will need to be validated)